# random.choice on Enum

Tags: python, random, enums

I would like to use `random.choice` on an `Enum`.

I tried:

```
class Foo(Enum):
    a = 0
    b = 1
    c = 2
bar = random.choice(Foo)
```

But this code fails with a `KeyError`. How can I choose a random member of `Enum`?

Comment: Have you read this: https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-ideas/2013-October/023673.html

Comment: @jonrsharpe: that post misses that `random.choice()` is documented to take a *sequence*, not an iterable. `Enum` is iterable, but not a sequence. It doesn't support *indexing by integers*. Also see the [response by Nick](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-ideas/2013-October/023675.html).

Answer (score 130, accepted):

An `Enum` is not a *sequence*, so you cannot pass it to `random.choice()`, which tries to pick an index between 0 and `len(Foo)`. Like a dictionary, index access to an `Enum` instead expects enumeration *names* to be passed in, so `Foo[<integer>]` fails here with a `KeyError`.

You can cast it to a list first:

```
bar = random.choice(list(Foo))
```

This works because `Enum` [*does* support iteration](https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html#iteration).

Demo:

```
>>> from enum import Enum
>>> import random
>>> class Foo(Enum):
...     a = 0
...     b = 1
...     c = 2
... 
>>> random.choice(list(Foo))
<Foo.a: 0>
```