# How to change the base value of auto in python Enum?

Tags: python, python-3.x, enums

Assuming I have the following code, how can I change the base value of auto so that Animal.ant is an arbitrary value, e.g. 10, rather than 1?

```
from enum import Enum, auto

class Animal(Enum):
    ant = auto()
    bee = auto()
    cat = auto()
    dog = auto()
```

Comment: Have you read https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html#using-automatic-values? What are you actually trying to achieve here? This seems like an XY problem.

Comment: The answer for your question can be found in following link
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24243500/python-3-4-random-choice-on-enum

Comment: @YatShan no, that's not the same

Comment: The entire point of ``auto`` is already to produce arbitrary but consistent values. The precise method is reserved as an implementation detail. Setting an auto value to a specific one, say 10, is *less* arbitrary. What is your goal, and in how far do you need more arbitrary values?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want certain members to have certain values, just assign them:

```
class Animal(Enum):
    ant = 10
    bee = auto()
    cat = auto()
    dog = auto()
```

And that will automatically adjust the values of succeeding members:

```
>>> list(Animal)
[<Animal.ant: 10>, <Animal.bee: 11>, <Animal.cat: 12>, <Animal.dog: 13>]
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use `_generate_next_value_` to change the way `auto()` select the value. For instance :

```
from enum import Enum, auto

class Auto_10(Enum):
    def _generate_next_value_(name, start, count, last_values):
        if name == "ant":
            return 10
        else:
           return last_values[-1] + 1

class Animal(Auto_10):
    ant = auto()
    bee = auto()
    cat = auto()
    dog = auto()
```